# Search orphaned uploaded files from announcement list

Tags: 2010, list, document

We have a couple of announcement lists where the files were uploaded instead of attached. Some of these announcements were deleted but the files are still there.

Is it possible to do a search of these orphaned files to mark for deletion?

We have SharePoint 2010 Standard.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of SharePoint you are Using?

I think your best bet is use the Codeplex SharePoint Manager tool.

For SharePoint 2013 http://spm.codeplex.com/

For SharePoint 2010 donwload from here http://spm.codeplex.com/releases/view/97332

They also have for 2007.

Comment: I have SharePoint 2010 Standard. I believe I have this on the server. Not sure which option will let me do a search.